# JQuery autocomplete not working using data from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using this PHP/JQuery code:

```
<?php
        $return_arr = array();
        $sql2="SELECT * from contacts where status = 'Contact' and company = '".$_GET["company"]."' ";
        $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);
        while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2)) {
            $return_arr[] = array('label' => $result2["forename"].' '.$result2["surname"], 'value' => $result2["email"]);
        }
        $data = json_encode($return_arr);
        ?>
          <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var data = <?php echo $data; ?>;
            $("#contact_name").autocomplete({
                source:data,

            change: function(e, ui) {
                if (ui.item === null) {
                    alert("Contact Does Not Exist.\n\nCheck the box below to add the entered details as a new contact of this company");

                    $("#AddAsContact").css('display', 'block');
                    $("#AddAsContactLabel").css('display', 'block');
                 }
              },
              select: function(e, ui) {
                  e.preventDefault() // <--- Prevent the value from being inserted.
                  $("#contact_email").val(ui.item.value);
                  $(this).val(ui.item.label);

                  $("#AddAsContact").css('display', 'none');
                  $("#AddAsContactLabel").css('display', 'none');
                  $('#AddAsContact').prop('checked', false);
              }
        });
    });
      </script>
```

but the autocomplete function doesn't seem to be working. I am not receiving any results in the auto complete list, there is however data being returned in the `data` variable

I have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n492uf07/

UPDATE:

The `data` var has this data currently:

```
var data = [{"label":"Paul","value":"email@hello.com"},{"label":"Dave","value":"support@domain.com"}];
```

I have also tried the code from the JQuery website (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

http://jsfiddle.net/n492uf07/2/

and thats not working in a fiddle either

Comment: Can you improve the description as to why it "doesn't seem to be working"?

Comment: check my update, you could also check the fiddle to see what results you dont get :)

Comment: It would be better if you provided a minimal and verifiable example that does not require access to external resources. This makes easier for other to provide an answer to your question and helps future searchers that might benefit from your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You say you don't receive any results on the autocomplete list. Did you check whether the server is returning the expected data to the client?

Comment: @h7r yes it is returning the data

Comment: Can you post at least part of the rendered `var data = <?php echo $data; ?>;` ?

Answer (score 1):

In the provided jsfiddle there is no jQueryUI library included. Autocomplete is part of jQueryUI library so you have to include it.

Comment: that's what I was checking in the fiddle site! :D

Comment: there is one included?

Comment: Note the difference betweeen [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)